Where can I find the reference to the phrase "Virabhogya Vasundhara"?
Where can I find the reference to the phrase "Virabhogya Vasundhara"? It means the earth is enjoyed by the brave. My school teacher used to tell me this!

It is available in Shiva Purana Canto 2.5,Chapter 32 in Sanskrit version as per wisdomlib website:

शंखचूड़ उवाच |
राज्यं दास्ये न देवेभ्यो वीरभोग्य वसुन्धरा |
राणं दास्यामि ते रुद्र देवानां पक्षपतिने || 18 ||



I will never return the kingdom to the god. The earth shall be enjoyed by heroic warriors. O Śiva, I shall fight with you who are a partisan of the gods.


